# General CallBack using each with node-orm2

Tags: node.js, callback

I am using node-orm2 with express.
I am trying to delete multiple lines in a database using remove.
After all is deleted, i'd like to call a callback when i'm sure everything is done.

```
var idArray = [{id: 2}, {id: 5}];
```

I tried :

```
Person.find({or:idArray}).each().remove().save(function(){
    res.writeHead(301, {Location: '/home'});
    res.end();
});
```

but i'm told : cannot used remove on undefined.

So I have to do my method remove inside each

```
Person.find({or:idArray}).each(function(element){
    element.remove();
})
.save(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.writeHead(301, {Location: '/home'});
        res.end();
    },2000);
});
```

But the callback **save** is called before each **remove** is done.

So for the moment i'm using a timeout but I hope there is a better method.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Person.find({or:idArray}).remove(function (err) {
    // handle the err here !
    res.writeHead(301, {Location: '/home'});
    res.end();
});
```

According to the [documentation](http://dresende.github.io/node-orm2/), this should work.

Comment: Thank you.
Didn't think it was working with multiple results.